# Framework 7 Vue2: Error in Mounted Hook for this.$f7

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I'm trying to use the Framework 7 api for

this.$f7.showPreloader()

```
 mounted() {
this.getPosts();
```

},

```
methods: {
  getPosts() {
    this.$f7.showPreloader();
    var self = this 
    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => {
          self.posts = response.data 
          self.$f7.hidePreloader();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
},
```

When the app loads, it gives a Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$f7 is undefined". However when I call it as a @click event, it works

```
clickme() {
    this.getPosts();
},
```

How do I call the F7 api object from the mounted event hook correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this may not be the final answer but this is the best I got.

There is a special hook for f7 Vue called

```
methods: {

onF7Init: function () {
    //do some code here  
    });
  }
}
```

This a special hook that occurs after F7 framework has been init after mounted. Put it in your methods. Apparently nobody wrote this in the documentation. If you put window.f7 here, the object will be defined and you can use it.